# Does Erase deletes heap memory used by element of stl unordered map

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map, erase

I have an unordered map of int and string into which values are inserted by reference.I want to erase some elements from map and reduce the malloc memory used, but I can't see reduction in memory.
Is it possible to reduce malloc memory using erase? Will rehash help after erase?

```
typedef typename std::unordered_set<N> ChangeObjSet;
ChangeObjSet _changeObjSet;

template <class N>
void MdmNameCacheImplMIWithStripEscape<N>::insertChangedStatus(const N &obj)
 {
    _changeObjSet.insert(obj);
 }

typename ChangeObjSet::iterator it = _changeObjSet.begin();
   for(;it != _changeObjSet.end();)
    {
     auto s = it;
    it++;
   _changeObjSet.erase(s);
}
```

Comment: "I can't see reduction in memory" what does that mean? How would you see a reduction?

Comment: The question could be clearer if you could show us some code like the definition of the map and how you insert elements, or even a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @churill Added code

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Reduction in malloc memory after erasing some elements

Comment: and what does that mean? There is no `malloc` involved (at least not visibly) when using a map

Comment: lets say you erase an element, then how to you measure the memory occupied by the map ?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 insert internally calls malloc to allocate memory for element to be inserted , I am using linux stat stream to get malloc memory

Answer (score 2):

> I am using linux stat stream to get malloc memory

Memory assigned by the OS to your process is not necessarily the same as memory you are using currently. Releasing memory back to the OS for each object that gets deleted would be horribly inefficient. You may see no decrease in memory assigned to the process until it terminates.

Answer (score 1):

In case the item itself is stored in the map (and not a pointer) it will be deleted when using erase.
If the map itself shrinks after erase may depends on the implementation of the specific map you are using.

Some implementations may reuse previously erased table entries for newly inserted items although I think most implementations don't. Are you using STD library?

Comment: I am using stl set

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I am facing issue in map and set both